# Is it possible to swap FileField's filename during download/referencing on FE?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django+DRF to allow upload/keep/serve user uploaded asset files. I need to let users to download the uploaded assets later. Upon a file upload I need to md5-hash its real name and save it to filesystem with that hash as the filename. Then, when the user wants to download/view it on FE, say he's uploaded a file 'cute_cat.jpg', I want him to get the file named 'cute_cat.jpg' and not 3c808e77fc1b0aee4435533690be458d (the name is one problem, the other one is that browser serves files w/o extensions as application/octet-stream and I want it to render '.jpg' (originally) files as images)

I feel that I need to inject a HTTP header with 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=cute_cat.jpg' (I'm storing the real filename in DB) somewhere on the way to DRF's Response(), but I'm not sure at which point I'm to do this and even if it's possible...
I've tried a bunch of stuff, mainly implementing custom fields for the serializer and injecting a custom URL there, but obviously that's not the way to it, because there's nowhere to inject headers to a text URL and there's no point trying to output a Request object with headers in an API view...

This is my model:

```
def get_full_path(instance, filename):
  return '/'.join([
    instance.user.name,
    hashlib.md5(filename.encode()).hexdigest()
  ])

class CustomAsset(models.Model):
  file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False, upload_to=get_full_path)
  real_file_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
  user = models.ForeignKey(...)
```

Nothing is overriden in serializer/API view.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What's is FE here?

Comment: FE=frontend, BE=backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to understand in the API, all you can return is the URL.

Now it's the browser duty to handle the file formatting and content type management. 
What you will need to do here is to manage the file through your application controller. When you return the url you return the url something like.

```
http://example.com/file/<md5>
```

And this url when accessed serves the file via a controller, with modified content disposition header and returns the file as response.

A simple example would look like.

In your urls.py , Add a new route.

```
url(r'^file/(?P<identifier>[\w\d\-_]+)$', custom_file_server, name="custom_file_server"),
```

And then serve the file according to your needs. 
A simple example would something like this.

```
def custom_file_server(request, identifier):
    ## Get the file name from db by querying from identifier
    file_name = "abc.jpg"
    absolute_file_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "media/"+identifier)
    response = FileResponse(open(absolute_file_path, 'rb'))
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename={}".format(file_name)
    response['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
    return response
```

The above code is not tested but the concept remains this. 
Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: thanks a lot, I did eventually override the retrieve method in my API view, but the code is essentially the same, I did use FileResponse also. That's, of course, not the ideal result, but I guess there's no way to do it like I wanted, oh well, this will suffice for now